# GTK, how to dynamically change text in label while keeping marksetup

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, label

basically i have a label with this attributes:

```
gtkwidget *lbl_Example;

lbl_Example = gtk_label_new("Text example1");

gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(lbl_Example), "<span font_desc=\"sans 10\">Text example2</span>);
```

Then i just have a callback where i call a function `Text_change`, i send the widget btn and gpointer to my label, and i just change the text again:

```
gtk_label_set_text("Final text");
```

the problem is the text completely loses the format given previosly by `set_markup`, and i cant figure out if there is a way i can place my ghcar variable inside the format of `set_markup` cause i just get the label text to be the name of the variable not the content.

Or a way to give format to the labels, since i cant properly get my codeblocks to recognize `Gtk_Css_Provider` functions or declarations in general.

Im workin on simple programs for now i apologize if my question is kinda dumb.

Answer (score 1):

`gtk_label_set_markup` doesn't set rules to style your text, it just parses given markuped string and sets it as label (with all styles applied). Thus, in your code you set the label to "example1", then to "example2" and then to "final text".

If your markup is complicated (e.g. something like `"<span style=\"italic\">%s</span><span style=\"bold\">%s</span>"`) you should pass a pointer to a place, where you can obtain both format and data

If it is simple you can:

- use `gtk_label_set_attributes`
- put the format string straight to callback (or `#define` it)